# Pickerview within enclosing view

Tags: iphone

using iphone sdk 4.0. I have added a UIPickerView to a view. I want the UIPickerView 
to be NON transparent ( as it is) but i want the background view to have an alpha of 0.3.

THis is so that the upper portion of the view (which is full size screen) is see through
and the lower portion which has the picker is solid. However when i set the alpha for the 
background view its affecting the pickerview and making that seethrough.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your UIPickerView view and background view are inside the same view hierarchy.  If you are setting the alpha on a view, all subviews will be effected by it.  Ensure that your "background" view is really in the background and not the parent of the UIPickerView.

EDIT:

You should be able to create a hierarchy in IB like this:

```
 - UView (root view)
     - background view
         - children of the background view (optional)
     - picker view
         - children of the picker view (optional)
     - other view
         - children of the other views
             - grand children ... etc
```

In this scenario, the "background" and the other views at that level all have the same parent, so they are siblings.

Comment: Thanks , I have a viewcontroller which in IB  came with a view so i just added my picker to the view.

So how can i make the view that the picker has to be added to become a background view, becomes it seems to me that it always is the parent